# How flush property works in SimpleFileChannel

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

As per [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.SimpleFileChannel.html):

> The flush property specifies whether each log message is flushed
> immediately to the log file (which may hurt application performance,
> but ensures that everything is in the log in case of a system crash),
> Valid values are:
>
> true: Every essages is immediately flushed to the log file (default).
>
> false: Messages are not immediately flushed to the log file.

I am confused with `false` value as **not immediately** is very confusing, because **not immediately** could mean **never** as well as **sometime**.

Can anyone please confirm that if that meant **never** or **sometime** (if latter, can you please clarify when?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When flush property is false, flushing is left to the default underlying platform behavior.

For details on what the exact behavior is for your OS when flush is false, refer to the documentation for [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (never called explicitly by Poco when flush property is false) on Windows and std::ostream (never flushed explicitly by Poco when flush property is false) on other operating systems.